# The total opposite (contradiction) of Infallible

Tags: contractions

I am looking for a word that means "can do no right"
Fallible is not the word I am looking for since that means "can do wrong"

Comment: Can you give some details about the person  you have in mind?

Comment: I can’t think of a single word, but *ill-starred* or *accident-prone* might work. A lot depends on the tone of your message - is the problem due to luck, or a lack of competence and judgement?

Comment: For example, the Muslim prophet Muhammad or former president Obama, were incapable of doing any wrong, and everything they did was considered right and praised by their followers.  Whether it is marrying a 6 yo girl or calling a stand down in Benghazi while US agents were being slaughtered, the followers praised their deeds.

Comment: On the other hand, Trump is always wrong on everything he does in the eyes of his critics.  So, in effect, He can do no right.